# Custom MembershipProvider IN ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to extend membershipProvider to use my own table.
I did a new asp.net mvc 4 site, extend memberShipProvider and added my customProvider in web.config under System.web

Now when i'm running the app, i've this issue:

```
 Erreur de configuration
Description : Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement d'un fichier de        configuration requis pour répondre à cette demande. Veuillez consulter ci-dessous les     détails relatifs à l'erreur en question, puis modifier votre fichier de configuration de manière appropriée.

Message d'erreur de l'analyseur: Cette méthode ne peut pas être appelée lors de la phase d'initialisation de pré-démarrage de l'application.

Erreur source:


Ligne 34 :       <providers>
Ligne 35 :         <clear/>
Ligne 36 :         <add name="CustomMemberProvider" type="erp.DAL.Connection.CustomMemberProvider" />
Ligne 37 :       </providers>
Ligne 38 : </membership>


Fichier source : E:\developpement vs\erp\erp\web.config    Ligne : 36
```

In extending membershipprovider, i could use the AccountController and the views already created at the start of the new project MVC4?
Do you have a solution and a good tutorial to use it in mvc4

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote a custom membership provider try adding the following to your web.config to disable the simple membership provider:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Also you might need to specify the name of your provider as being the default one:

```
<providers defaultProvider="CustomMemberProvider">
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMemberProvider" type="erp.DAL.Connection.CustomMemberProvider" />
</providers>
```

Comment: So i need to add appSettings in web.config? under the default provider in System.web :

After this, do i have to rewrite AccountController and the views generated a the begining of the app?

thanks for your help

Comment: You shouldn't need the app setting if you don't call WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection, as the default implementation uses whatever membership is configured unless the initialize method is called.